# Track changes in indices for numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, set, transition

I have a simple problem with Python, but would need it to be solved in less than a minute.

I have two 1D numpy arrays, x1 and x2 which can have different sizes, but count around 300,000 -> 500,000 elements. There is no repetition, values are not necessarily sorted.

x2 represents a transformed x1 array (so x1 is before, x2 is after).

First, I can obtain which elements were "inserted" (I) or "discarded" (D), or even staying (S) between the two steps.

```
I = list(set(x2) - set(x1))
D = list(set(x1) - set(x2))
S = list(set(x1) & set(x2))
```

Now, I would like to get a "transition" (T) array which give me the change in index of the elements between the two steps.

Let me give an example:
`x1 = [3,5,2,6]`
`x2 = [1,6,5,3,7]`
We have `S=[3,5,6], I=[1,7], D=[2]`

Here, we have for each x1 element:

- for 3: it goes from index 0 in x1 to 3 in x2 -> `3`
- for 5: it goes from index 1 in x1 to 2 in x2 -> `2`
- for 2: it gets discarded -> `nan`
- for 6: it goes from index 3 in x1 to 1 in x2 -> `1`

So I would like T to be `[3, 2, nan, 1]` (associated with `I = [1,7]`, I have all the information I actually need.

My first (simple) idea was to do:

```
T = []
for i in range(len(x1)):
    for j in range(len(x2)):
        if x1[i] == x2[j]:
            transition[i] = j
            break
```

However, the time to solve that is very large.
So what I am looking for is a time-efficient way of creating this "transition array", and also to know how such thing is called in a more formal way.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

There are array functions like `np.unique`, `np.argsort`, `np.isin`, `np.in1d` that can be used to test for set like operations. I believe there are some other related `set` functions.

But a basic way of comparing arrays is with an outer '==':

```
In [60]: x1 = [3,5,2,6]; x2 = [1,6,5,3,7]
In [61]: np.array(x1)[:,None]==np.array(x2)
Out[61]: 
array([[False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False]])
```

Going down the rows, 0,1,3 have one True, 2 has none.  That looks like your `T`.

Going across columns, 0 and 4 are all False.  That's your `I`.

```
In [62]: Out[61].any(axis=1)
Out[62]: array([ True,  True, False,  True])
In [63]: np.array(x1)[Out[61].any(axis=1)]
Out[63]: array([3, 5, 6])
In [64]: np.array(x2)[Out[61].any(axis=0)]
Out[64]: array([6, 5, 3])
In [65]: np.array(x2)[~Out[61].any(axis=0)]
Out[65]: array([1, 7])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Based on this, I wrote this script that gives T and I.

    import numpy as np
    import random
    N = 350000
    x1 = np.array(random.sample(range(N), int(N)))
    x2 = np.array(random.sample(range(N), int(N)))
    M = x1[:,None]==x2
    r = np.argwhere(M)
    T = np.nan * np.ones(x1.shape)
    T[r[:,0]] = r[:,1]
    I = np.where(np.isnan(T))[0]

This is more efficient, but still takes around 6 minutes for this to run. Is there anything I should do to accelerate this?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Based on this, I wrote this script that gives T and I. 

`import numpy as np   `
  ``
`import random N = 350000   `
  ``
`x1 = np.array(random.sample(range(N), int(N)))   `
  ``
`x2 = np.array(random.sample(range(N), int(N)))   `
  ``
`M = x1[:,None]==x2   `
  ``
`r = np.argwhere(M)   `
  ``
`T = np.nan * np.ones(x1.shape)   `
  ``
`T[r[:,0]] = r[:,1]   `
  ``
`I = np.where(np.isnan(T))[0]   `

This is more efficient, but still takes around 6 minutes for this to run. Is there anything I should do to accelerate this?  `